# Combination formula?

Tags: combinatorics

I know there is a formula for finding the different combinations when you are dividing them in groups:

$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!\, r!}$$

However, what if you just want to find the number of combinations for lets say $4$ items (without repetition) without dividing the items into groups?

I remember learning it. I think it was something to the power of $n$... I would appreciate support.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean the number of ways arranging $n$ items ?

Comment: The number of combinations for arranging n items.

Comment: @anonymous; can you give an example

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I am sorry but I am a bit confused. I read somewhere that the total number of combinations from a collection of n objects is 2^n. I 'm just not sure how that has anything to do with the formula I first wrote in my question.

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {n}{r} = 2^n$

Comment: which is like $\emptyset$, 1,2,3,4, 12,13,14,...,123,124,...,1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean permutation of $n$ elements.

The formula to obtain this number is $$n!$$

**Example**

$n=4$, then you have the elements $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$. The permutations are:

$$1)~1,2,3,4\\2)~1,2,4,3\\3)~1,3,2,4\\4)~1,3,4,2\\5)~1,4,2,3\\6)~1,4,3,2\\7)~2,1,3,4\\8)~ 2,1,4,3\\9)~2,3,1,4\\10)~2,3,4,1\\11)~2,4,1,3\\12)~2,4,3,1\\13)~3,1,2,4\\14)~3,1,4,2\\15)~3,2,1,4\\16)~3,2,4,1\\17)~3,4,1,2\\18)~3,4,2,1\\19)~4,1,2,3\\20)~4,1,3,2\\21)~4,2,1,3\\22)~4,2,3,1\\23)~4,3,1,2\\24)~4,3,2,1$$

Comment: is there another way (other than lexilogical) of ordering permutations (using a method)?

Comment: I guess there is. But how this could help to answer?

Comment: i was just wondering...

Comment: try to ask this question, it sounds interesting :D

Comment: what do you think? 'is there a more natural ordering of permutations than lexigraphical?'

Comment: Any permutation of the lexicographic ordering is an ordering itself.

Comment: In the case that $n=4$, then you will have $24!$ possible ordering.

Comment: yes, but not all of them have got simple, natural generators.

Comment: There is one way. 1) Perform a lexicographic ordering; 2) Choose a permutation of the positions (for istance, $1 \rightarrow 3, 2 \rightarrow 1, 3 \rightarrow 4, 4 \rightarrow 2$); 3) Exchange each permutation according to the permutation of the positions.

Comment: that's neither simple nor natural

Comment: @the_candyman I would like one for the combinations not the permutations.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. So, I you want to find to find the number of combinations for 5 objects then there is only one combination because order does not matter. Is that right?

Comment: @anonymous yeah, you got the point man!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I think you should consider to create a new question on the topic. I'm quite sure you'll find a lot of useful answers by the community.